# How to teleport someone in ROBLOX after speaking to a npc

Tags: roblox

I need to know how to teleport a player after you speak to them in Roblox studio can someone please help me?

Comment: Heyo, what have you tried? What isn't working? Have you looked at any of the tutorials on the DevHub for [NPC dialog](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Usage-of-dialogs) or [TeleportService](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Teleporting-Between-Places) yet?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know to teleport a player to another player is to set their HumanoidRootPart CFrame to another player's HumanoidRootPart CFrame.
For teleporting a player to another Experience/World, I'd recommend using TeleportService as Kylaaa suggested.

To run the code for teleportation after the dialog ends would use a :Connect().

Example code for the CFrame teleportation, where "char" is the character of the player talking to the NPC and "target" is a random player's character.

```
char.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = target.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame
```